# Appending a tuple in to a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

How to create a Tuple and appending in to a single List ?

a = 1, b= 2, c = 3, d = 4

I want it as ,
[(1,2) , (3,4)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean: `my_list = [(a, b), (c, d)]` ?

That will create a list with two tuples: `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> t1=(1,2)
>>> t2=(3,4)
>>> l1 = []
>>> l1.append(t1)
>>> l1.append(t2)
>>> print l1
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't make your question clear enough. If you are going to read a list of coordinates like x1, y1, x2, y2, .... , xn, yn, and then make it a list of tuple, do this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
xy = [(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in xrange(0, len(l), 2)]
```